# python getting many to many from model mixin returning None

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model:

```
class Employee(models.Model, MyMixin):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, blank=True)
```

and a mixin class:

```
class MyMixin(object):

    def my_m2m(self, field):
        field_value = getattr(self, field)
        print(field_value)
        // do something with many to many field

emp = Employee()
emp.my_m2m("items")
```

It gives me the result like `employee.Item.None` while printing `emp.my_m2m("items")`
 on console.

If I do `emp.items.all()` it gives me the result but I cant get it by name.

Why is it not giving the list of item associated with it ?

Am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, adding `.all()` gives the result, so you need to add that to your dynamic lookup:

```
field_value = getattr(self, field).all()
```